# Python Automatically pick an analysis based on the dataset

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, automation, build-automation

I have ten time-series datasets coming from various cities. I want to automate the analysis process. I am trying to create a program structure to automate the analysis process and develop the script.

**My input data:**
Provided data for each city
[image]

Example format of Time-series dataset-1:

```
                      ForestTemp    PlaygndTemp    Airpoty_Humidity ...
2022-01-01 08:00:00       25             30             35          ...
2022-01-01 09:00:00       28             35             41          ...
```

**What I want to do:**
I will provide meta-information (as defined in the above tables) about each data set to the program. Now the program should pick up the type of analysis it should do. All the datasets will have different column names, but they could be of the same type of measurement.

[image]

I would like to know about the already developed modules, if any are available. I planned to create a `meta_file.xlsx` and provide information about each data set in a column. Then the program will loop through each column (is one data set) and provide numerical results, plots, etc. Do you have any suggestions? I don't want to reinvent the wheel again.